# Javascript how to count unique clicks on several links

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, count, unique

For example if they are say 10 unique clicks on the page I have this code which will count a click on each one:

```
function modify_qty(val) {
var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

if (new_qty < 0) {
    new_qty = 0;
}

document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
return new_qty;
}

<a onClick="modify_qty(1)">link</a>
```

But the problem is if I click the same link it counts it again and again. What I want is that for example with 10 links on the page, the maximum count will be 10 and each link can only be clicked once.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button after click in this way, your each unique button will clicked only once
hence you will get your desired output.

alternately, you can assign a class to button on click (in case if you dont want to disable it)

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the links that have been clicked via a closure variable, and return from the function when the link has already been clicked. This could also be done with self-removing event listeners.

```
<a href="#" id="1" onClick="modify_qty(1, this.id)">link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onClick="modify_qty(1, this.id)">link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3" onClick="modify_qty(1, this.id)">link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="4" onClick="modify_qty(1, this.id)">link 4</a>
<a href="#" id="5" onClick="modify_qty(1, this.id)">link 5</a>


modify_qty = (function(){
    var clickedLinks = [];
    return function(val, linkId) {
        // check if link has been clicked    
        if(clickedLinks.indexOf(linkId) > -1){
            return;
        }
        // add link to clicked array and process
        clickedLinks.push(linkId);

        var qty = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
        var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

        if (new_qty < 0) {
            new_qty = 0;
        }

        lastVal = val;
        return new_qty;
    };
})();
```

Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4yorv72w/1/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. With that code it doens't count clicks at all anymore.

Comment: @Hasen - There was a missing '}', check the updated version.

Comment: Ok now it counts a link when clicked and will not count it again, but only that one link can be clicked. All other links cannot be clicked either. They are all different unique links but of course they all have the same property:

onClick="modify_qty(1);

in the url....maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Do they all pass 1 to the function? Different values should work. This prevents it from running with the same value twice in a row. @Hasen

Comment: I don't know whether they all pass 1 to the function or not but it stays stuck at 1. I can't pass different values 'cos I just want to count clicks so each one should be 1. I feel this is almost working though...

Comment: Ok that looks great although it doesn't actually add up anything as it is. So do I need to add in "document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;" to get it to add up? It doens't seem to work addin gthat in the end before "return new_qty;"

Comment: Your code is missing a counter that displays the clicks like this: <input id="qty" value="0" />

Comment: ?
Ok I'll just try and figure out the last part myself. It seems quite strange. Like it is now with me adding that last line of code in to count clicks, it just changes the number of clicks to 10,8,4 weird numbers like that instead of adding 1 to the count each time.